CUPS on docker stops printing when printer is restarted
We have the CUPS container from anujdatar/cups-docker.
The problem is the CUPS stops printing when the printer lost connection to the USB — i.e. the printer is turned off/on (restarts) or the USB cable is disconnected and reconnected.
The docker compose file:
version: "3.8"
services:
    cups:
        image: anujdatar/cups
        container_name: cups
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "631:631"
        devices:
            - /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb
        environment:
            - CUPSADMIN=<user>
            - CUPSPASSWORD=<password>
            - TZ="America/Sao_Paulo"
        volumes:
            - /path/to/cups:/etc/cups
            - /path/to/cups/log:/var/log/cups
            - /path/to/cups/data:/var/spool/cups

At this link there is a discussion with the project leader: https://github.com/anujdatar/cups-docker/issues/15

To workaround the problem we monitored the USB devices changes, if any occur then we restart the CUPS container.
1. Create a file named restart_docker_container_cups.sh, then edit it with nano restart_docker_container_cups.sh and add the script that will restart the container:
#!/bin/bash 
docker restart your-cups-container-name

2. Make it executable with: chmod +x restart_docker_container_cups.sh
3. Configure the “udev” to monitor the USB changes.
Go to /etc/udev/rules.d and create the file 99-usb.rules, then add the following to it:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb, ACTION=="add", RUN+="/path/to/restart_docker_container.sh"

This will restart the cups container every time an USB device trigger the add event.
OR: If you want to trigger the event only when the USB of the printer changes, use the vendor id and product id (use lsusb to get them) and add the following to the file:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="VID", ATTR{idProduct}=="PID", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/path/to/restart_docker_container.sh"

4. Restart the udev:
udevadm control --reload-rules
udevadm trigger

